# Is there a way to check if all the elements in an array are null in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to check if all the elements in an array are null in PHP?

For instance, I have an array `array(null,null,null,null)` - is there a way to check this scenario?

I am looking for a better way than just looping through the entire array and checking each element.

Comment: Sure, loop through it with `foreach` and test each element.

Comment: I meant a better way to do it.
As in some in built function

Comment: `array_unique($array) == array(null)` maybe.  __EDIT__ removed quotes

Comment: How about checking if the data is empty before inserting it into the array in the first place? If it's empty, it's not added in the array. An array is useless if it has no content

Comment: Any solution using `array_unique()` is *O(n)* in the best case, whereas a simple loop (and break) as @halfer suggests is *O(n)* only in the worst case. That means if you have a million items and the second item is not null, with `array_unique()` you'll still end up checking the remaining 999,998 items (not to mention potentially using quite a lot of memory) even though you already have your answer. Don't do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another simple way of making this work is to use the `max()` function.

```
max(array( 3, 4, null, null  ) )      # is 4
max(array( null, null, null, null)    # is null
```

Thus you can issue a simple `if( is_null(max($array)) ) { ... }` call.

Comment: This doesn't work if the array have mixed types: `print max(['a', new StdClass(), null])` results in `PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$nulls = array(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
var_dump(array_unique($nulls) === array(null)); // prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) would work:

```
function checkIsset($val) {
    return isset($val);
}
$arr = array(null, null, null, ..., null);
$filteredArr = array_filter($arr, 'checkIsset');
if (count($filteredArr)) {
  //not all null
} else {
  //all null
}
```

or `if (empty($filteredArr))` if you want the inverse.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, nope. it's more about the structure of how it would work.

Comment: Could you please provide working code or add the fact that it is pseudocode?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, what's not working? Have you tried it out?

Comment: I haven't tested it (then again I didn't try to answer), but I think you will get an error on `isset` as callback.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, i just checked, and you're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```php
if ($arr && count(array_filter($arr, 'is_null')) === count($arr)) {
   echo "Array is all NULLs\n";
}
```

This will call echo only if all elements of `$arr` are NULLs.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

like this:

```
$nulls = array(null,null,null,null,null);
if(count(array_filter($nulls)) == 0){
  echo "all null (or false)";
}
```

Dunno what you expect in this array, but this lumps false in with the nulls...

Comment: I think you meant `count($removenulls) == 0`

Comment: if you used `array(0, '', null, array());` this would fail. `array_filter` simply checks for falsey values, not `null` values.

Comment: My answer was up before I commented, then I noticed yours was similar.

Comment: @JKirchartz have you considered testing some of you tries?